# Extract uppercase words from a string

Tags: php, regex

Edit i resolve my problem. 
This is the solution

```
$string = "Hello my Name is Paloppa. Im' 20 And? Hello! Words I  Io Man";     
// Word boundary before the first uppercase letter, followed by any alphanumeric character
preg_match_all( '/(?<!^)\b[A-Z][a-z]{1,}\b(?!["!?.\\\'])/', $string, $matches);
print_r( $matches[0] );
```

Now i have one more question

Every time it founds a word, the word is inserted in a position of the array.

If i have this phrase "Whats is your Name and Surname? My Name And Surname' is Paolo Celio and Serie A Iim 25 Thanksbro Bro Ciao"
this is my code

```
    $string = "Whats is your Name and Surname? My Name And Surname' is Paolo Celio and Serie A Iim 25 Thanksbro Bro Ciao";     
// Word boundary before the first uppercase letter, followed by any alphanumeric character
preg_match_all( '/(?<!^)\b([A-Z][a-z]+ +){1,}\b(?!["!?.\\\'])/', $string, $matches);
print_r( $matches[0] );
```

the output is the following

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Name 
        [1] => Name And Surname 
        [2] => Paolo Celio 
        [3] => Serie 
        [4] => Iim 
        [5] => Thanksbro Bro 
       )
```

Why it doesn't join Serie A instead it didn't print A?
Why the last word doesn't in the output?

Thanks

EDIT 
I resolve my problem, this is my REGEX

```
preg_match_all('/(?<!^)\b[A-Z]([a-z0-9A-Z]| [A-Z]){1,}\b(?!["!?.\\\'])/', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't nee 'Hi' in the expected output too?

Comment: So do you want Capitalized words only or any word containing an uppercase character?

Comment: I don't want the word that start after point and the first word if is the first word. So i have this phrase"Hi all. My name is Paloppa", the return is " Paloppa no @man0v

Comment: There is a contradiction between your code and your result. Your code selects `My` (in `My name and ...`) but your resulting array don't show this `My`. What is the correct behaviour, and why?

Comment: @Toto I forgot it sorry. But i can do what i saied? Paolo Celio in the same array position?

Comment: You can certainly do it if you can explain the rule, why these two words must be joined and not some other? In the sentence: `What is Your Name And Surname? My name and surname is Paolo Celio` should `Your Name And` be joined?

Comment: @Toto i want joined the consecutive words that start with a capital letter. So if i have the phrase "What is Your Name And Surname? My name and surname is Paolo Celio" i want join just Paolo Celio. if we have the phrase "What is Your Name And Surname? My name and surname is Paolo Celio Garden" i wnat join Paolo Celio Garden

Comment: OK, but why not `Your Name And`?

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question to include the answer, otherwise the original question and answers become useless without context. It's better to ask a new question. Review [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what to do with answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Toto because for exemple the join Paolo Celio is the name and surname. Or for example if i have Premier League i want join it, but if i have Your Name And, i don't want join it or if i have Hi Cold Where i don't want join it.

Comment: @Toto The conditions that i thinking is the folowing: check the initial phrase. If in this phrase there are 2-3 or more consecutive words, join it. How can i do this with preg Match?

Comment: It's not matching 'Serie A' or the last word because the rule `[A-Z][a-z]+ +` matches "an uppercase letter followed by *one or more* lowercase letters *and one or more* spaces".

Comment: I resolved it! Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You can use..

```
<?php
      $test="the Quick brown Fox jumps Over the Lazy Dog";
      preg_match_all("/[A-Z][a-z]*/",$test,$op);
      $output = implode(' ',$op[0]);
      echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: While this works with the text given be aware that there is a short coming to the expression as it will also falsely flag words like noWay (capitalised letter within the word). This might be something that the OP can live with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if i have this phrase "Hello my name is Paloppa. I'm 20 And i love Football" i want this output " Paloppa And Football" What is the preg_match_all condition?

Answer (score 0):

To extract full words you'll need to use word boundaries and character classes to match the remaining part of the word, and use lookbehinds to exclude previous content:

```
$string = "Hello my Name is Paloppa. I'm 20 And? Hello! Words' Man";     
// Word boundary before the first uppercase letter, followed by any alphanumeric character
preg_match_all( '/(?<!^)(?<!\. )\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\b(?!["!?\\\'])/', $string, $matches);
print_r( $matches[0] );
```

If you want Capitalized words only, excluding MixedCase words, replace `[a-zA-Z]` with just `[a-z]`.

Demo [here](https://3v4l.org/58nId)

Comment: thanks man, but if i have this phrase "Hello my Name is Paloppa. I'm 20 And? Hello! Words' Man" " the return is Name I.

Comment: @Paloppa If you have that phrase, what is the expected output? I get "Name Paloppa And Hello Words Man", not what you describe...

Comment: yes i know, but i don't understand what is the Regular expression for my new request. Can you help me please? Thanks. I don't want print the words that finish with this Special characters ( . ? ! ' ") how can i do this?

Comment: what this the preg_match?

Comment: Ok but, in the output i want I and i don't want Paloppa. Moreover if i have a word that finish with " he gives me error. So i can do? My phrase is "Hello my Name is Paloppa. I'm 20 And? Hello! Words' Woman" Man" and the output must has Name I Man

Comment: @Paloppa: Why do you want `I`, it is followed by `'`? You're continuously changing your request, please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56559605/edit) and give more test cases with expected result.

Comment: Whi if i have Exemple: or i have Guess, or other special characters  they doesn't apper in the output? With this condition we eliminate all words with special characters like : , ; ' ? ! etc

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly complicated, when it comes to edge cases, yet we would simply define two char classes based on our desired outputs and inputs, maybe with a word boundary, with an expression similar to:

```
(?=[^I'])\b([A-Z][a-z'é]+)\b
```

and we would expand it based on our cases.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vaijcj/1/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/(?=[^I\'])\b([A-Z][a-z\'é]+)\b/m';
$str = 'Hello my name is Paloppa. I\'m 20 And i love Football.
Hello my name is Chloé. I\'m 20 And i love Football.
Hello my name is Renée O\'neal. I\'m 20 And i love Football.';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can fastest way use.

```
$test="Hi There this Is my First Job";
preg_match_all('/[A-Z][a-z]*/', $test, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

$res=array();

foreach( $matches[0] as $key=> $value){

    $res[]=$value[0];
}

print_r($res);
```

OUTPUT:

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Hi
    [1] => There
    [2] => Is
    [3] => First
    [4] => Job
)
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1f4e0c41bf438e625cdd93bfeb71a90065d14df4)

Comment: Updated the answers